# Происходит переброс на тот же домен только с www

Tags: php, .htaccess, modx

Привет. Имеется сайт под управлением modx revo 2.4.2. При переходе на domain.ru сайт открывается как-то странно, иконки становятся крупнее обычного, текст иногда вылезает за края. Затем, при переходе на страницу, к адресу сайта добавляется www и все становится нормальным. Плюс, в корневой папке есть папка old (старая версия сайта), при запросе domain.ru/old/ перебрасывает на главную, при www.domain.ru/old/ все нормально открывается. Подскажите, что делать и куда копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо стелать в .htaccess редирект в чтобы был один вариант с www или без www
как [здесь описано](http://seodiz.ru/htaccess-redirekt-s-www-i-bez-www-301)